# Obtener a partir de una lista de enteros el o los sobconjuntos únicos bajo una condición

Tags: python, lista

Estoy trabajando en un programa que dada una lista con números reales,  me devuelva sublistas de 3 elementos, que la suma de ellos de 0
Entrada: [-25, -10, -7, -3, 2, 4, 8, 10]
Salida: [[-10, 2, 8], [-7, -3, 10]]

Mi código fuente es el siguiente:

```
    self.lista=[]
    self.listaFinal=[]
    suma= 0
    for x in self.numeros:
        for y in self.numeros:
            for z in self.numeros:
                suma= x+y+z
                
                if suma == 0:
                    
                    
                    self.lista.append(x)
                    self.lista.append(y)
                    self.lista.append(z)
                    
                   # print(self.lista)
                    self.listaFinal.append(self.lista)
                    self.listaFinal.sort()

            
                #print(self.lista)
                suma = 0
                self.lista=[]
            self.conjunto= list(set(self.listaFinal))

    return self.conjunto
```

Pero me da un error cuando ocupo la función `Set`, el error es el siguiente

`'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''`

¿Alguna idea del porque me esta fallando la lógica?

Saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error es un error de conceptos. Los sets, o conjuntos, son objetos que en sí son mutables (podemos agregar y remover elementos de ellos), pero los objetos dentro del set no pueden ser objetos mutables, por lo tanto, no puedes crear sets que contengan elementos mutables, por ejemplo, no puedes hacer un set que contenga listas, un set que contenga sets, etc.

Podrías intentar crear un set que contenga tuples, esto es posible ya que los tuples no pueden ser editados (son inmutables).

Por si no sabes lo que son, los tuples son como las listas, colecciones de elementos ordenados, pero a diferencia de ellas no pueden ser editados, una vez que se crean no pueden modificarse. Se crean como las listas pero reemplazando los [] por ().

Ejemplo:

```
a=(1,4,6,2,3)
```

Puedes usar en el tuple los métodos de lista que no editan la misma, estos son, a.count(elemento) y a.index(elemento), pero NO puedes usar los demás como a.insert(), a.append(), etc.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si el resultado que buscas es la combinación única de listas de 3, 2, 1, N... elementos cuya suma sea igual a 0 te propongo lo siguiente:

```
# Encontrar todas las combinaciones con el módulo itertools:
from itertools import combinations

entrada = [-25, -10, -7, -3, 2, 4, 8, 10]

# Definir la cantidad de elementos en la sublistas:
n = 3
combinaciones = [list(combinacion) for combinacion in combinations(entrada,n)]

# Filtrar aquellas cuya suma sea de un valor como condicion:
condicion = 3
salida =  [x for x in combinaciones if sum(x) == condicion]
```

La salida será el conjunto de sublistas cuya suma sea = a tu valor de condición, en este caso siendo 3 la condición es: [[-7, 2, 8], [-3, 2, 4]]

Comment: Así se malgasta memoria con la lista de todas las combinaciones posibles. Se podría hacer mejor: `salida = [list(x) for x in combinations(entrada, n) if sum(x) == condicion]`